# Errors installing vue-storefront

Tags: vue.js, npm, yarnpkg, vue-storefront

When I run `yarn run dev` on the `vue-storefront`, it starts on `localhost:3000` and compiles successfully but then brings up this error.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\HP\Documents\vue-storefront\dist\c849e1b2bfa798743d30.hot-update.json'.
```

The `vue-storefront-api` works perfectly and runs on `localhost:8080`, but when I run `localhost:3000`, it says something went wrong. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: did you fix it? got same issue here

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `yarn cache clean`, and then `yarn run dev`. It would do the job.